# Disable image compression in word 2010

Tags: pdf, images, microsoft-word-2010

When I create a PDF document from word 2010 (or 2013), Images in the PDF file will be downsampled from the original file size (which has 300dpi resolution).

How can I disable the shrinking of the images in PDF? The printing quality suffers from this and I'd rather choose the compression myself.

There is an option to disable image compression but it does not seem to make a difference for created PDFs.

Comment: Can't you use a free PDF printer instead that might do the job better?

Comment: Can you recommend one? I don't know any.

Comment: Most "free" PDF creators I encountered so far have some sort of nagware inside. They add Advertising or stuff. So I'm not really happy about starting a wild goose chase to find one which might not add nagware and additionally supports higher Resolution. Ain't there some easier solution??

Comment: Is image compression turned off in Word?

Comment: Charlie, it is disabled but still it seems word does Limit the Images to 220dpi.

Comment: Karan, I heeded your comment and tried Adobe Acrobat Pro, it creates nicer PDF files. So I'll probably buy that one and be done with it, thanks! Funny Thing is, it changes the colors slightly (lessens contrast)

Comment: All right, try [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php), and if that's not good enough get Acrobat. (BTW, don't forget the '@' sign before someone's name if you want to notify them of your comment.)

Comment: @Karan, I tried Acrobat Pro, it works nicely up until page 200, then it "forgets" to embed the images into the PDF :(
I'll try Bullzip now, thanks!