# Word: How to prevent word scrapping images

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I like to produce nice documents wnd nice figures are part of it. As a tool of choice I use (lua)LaTeX and embedding figures consist of:

- prepare vector graphics in `figure.pdf` or high-resolution `figure.png`
- `\includegraphics[width=<width>]{figure}`

Job is done and result is really nice, no lines disappearing, no blur.

Now I am forced to use Word 2013 and I'm going slightly mad about it.

- When I include `figure.pdf` it gets pixelated, downsampled and many image options are disabled.
- When I include `figure.png` it is imported over whole page width. When I resize it to 8cm width, it is downsampled. Some lines vanish, contour lines become rubbish.

Is there a way how to keep the quality of embedded images?

I tried to rename the document, unzip it, replace the scrapped image in `filename\media\` folder by the original one, zip it and rename back to `.docx` but it cannot be opened.

---

Suggested question addresses the issue when `.pdf` file is created from `.docx` file. Especially the upsampling of low-resolution images and increaing the size during `.pdf` output. My problem is with including images and arranging them within the `.docx` file.

The answer, that solves *my* problem is disregarded in the linked question, since it *does not* solve their problem.

Comment: "Open File > Settings > Advanced, then in Image size and quality section, check option Do not compress images in files." -- Does that have any affect?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Please, make it an answer. PS does analogy to undocumentedmatlab.com exist for Office?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Microsoft Word 2010 from smoothing screenshots?](http://superuser.com/questions/272170/stop-microsoft-word-2010-from-smoothing-screenshots)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 more likely this one: http://superuser.com/questions/538341/disable-image-compression-in-word-2010?rq=1 . Byt your link has the answer in it as a byproduct.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Could You write an answer? Quoting OP's comment under the answer that solves my problem (and Your first comment suggested it as well):  
*I feel like I should clarify since this is getting so many up votes - this is a good setting to know about, but it doesn't affect the issue I'm having at all. – Herb Caudill*